# Azure Event Grid: Find out if a blob is being overwritten

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have wired an `EventGridTrigger` to Azure Functions and listen on `Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated` changes. So far, it seems to be working fine. However, I have observed that multiple events will be triggered for the same blob if the client overwrites it. I need to do some server-side processing only **once** per blob creation. Is there any metadata available to us to see how many times a blob has been overwritten?

As a workaround, I'm thinking of saving blob URI to a `Cosmos` container as a primary key to see if it's ever been processed before, but this sounds like overkill for something this trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 possible solutions:

1. Store the blob uri to an Azure Table (same as your sugestion with Cosmos but cheaper)
2. Turn on blob versioning an check that it is the first version of the blob before processing. Turning on versioning has a cost.
3. Check the code that updates the blob. Is it possible to us the BlockBlobClient and only update the affected block? Will this avoid BlobCreated being triggered on updated.

I would start with checking if option 3 was possible. If not do option 1.

Comment: 3 won't work because a malicious user can take the SAS token and upload an entirely new blob outside of my application since the token has write permissions. I wish there was a way to create a token with a one time write permission.

Comment: If you are worried about that you should probably change your design. Upload via a web app with authentication instead of directly to the storage account. That will also allow you to check if the blob allready exists.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I'll see if I can set up a Rest service and upload the chunks through it with authentication.